# Unable to start mule-standalone-3.5.0 server in my local system

Tags: java, mule, mule-studio

I am unable to start mule standalone server 3.5.0. in my Windows7 PC. My java version installed is "1.6.0_45" and it is 64 bit. I have set the Path, JAVA_HOME, MULE_HOME environment variables in system settings. While starting the mule server by running mule.exe from bin folder I am getting the following error.

Can you please anyone suggest me to get rid of this error.

```
C:\Applications\mule-standalone-3.5.0\bin>mule  
MULE_HOME is set to C:\Applications\mule-standalone-3.5.0  
Running in console/foreground mode by default, use Ctrl-C to exit...  
--> Wrapper Started as Console  
Launching a JVM...  
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Bad version number in .class file  
          at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)  
          at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)  
          at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)  
          at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)  
          at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)  
          at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)  
          at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)  
          at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)  
          at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)  
          at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)  
          at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(Unknown Source)    
Exception in thread "main"  
JVM exited while loading the application.  
CTRL-C trapped.  Shutting down.  
<-- Wrapper Stopped  
Terminate batch job (Y/N)?
```

Comment: Just FYI Java 6 is EOL since Feb 2013. Time to upgrade...

Answer (score 1):

The exceptions java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError are very often 100% right. I would triple check that you are not using an older version.

Mule 3.5 is built with Java 1.6 so it's very unlikely there is a problem unless you have the wrong JVM.

Comment: I have cross verified my java version, it is "1.6.0_45". But still i am getting this error while starting the server.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes yo have everything setted properly, but it's getting the java from somewhere else.
tyy to run a

C:\Applications\mule-standalone-3.5.0\bin>java -version

just in case, to see if you are using the correct java version.

By the way, the exception is on a mule class or is in a project of yours deployed in this mule runtime? (seems like the log you copied is truncated).

Comment: This error came while starting the server and there is no application deployed on the server. Also verified I am using the Java version 1.6.